# How to choose from a list of Regions for GPU instances in Amazon SageMaker?

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-sagemaker

I'm currently trying to do distributed GPU training with 2 instances of ml.p3.8xlarge and after 4 attempts I have not been able to start a training job with the spot instances since AWS did not have any available instances in my region.

How do I increase the number of regions I'm willing to choose from in SageMaker? At the moment I'm only using:

`sess.boto_region_name = us-east-1` (sagemaker session region)

But I'm assuming if I allow SageMaker to choose from other regions, I will be able to start a training job with spot instances.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most AWS services are regional-based, meaning they run in a given region and do not spread *beyond* one region.

If you wish to run SageMaker in multiple regions, you would need to launch it *separately* in each region. So, you would only be 'choosing' *one* region when requesting SageMaker to perform some work.

Comment: Yeah, I realized this later in the day and tried in us-east-2, but it didn't work since I don't have a GPU quota in that region. I'll either need to get spot instances in that region or just get in-demand instances and pay a bit more.